# how to hide\show items in ddl

Tags: javascript, ddl

I have a ddl control. I want to change the visibility of some items on the client-side (JS).
I only found methods to insert\remove items. 
But I only want to hide\show them.

Does someone has an idea how to do so ?

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "a ddl control"? There appears to be some confusion in the answers given so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the item and set its [edit]style.display[/edit] to "none":

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function hideItem() {
         document.getElementById("a3").style.display = "none";
      }
    </script>
    <body onload="hideItem()">
       <form>
          <select name="ddl" size="1">
            <option id="a1">Option 1</option>
            <option id="a2">Option 2</option>
            <option id="a3">Option 3</option>
            <option id="a4">Option 4</option>
            <option id="a5">Option 5</option>
          </select>
       </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @anothershrubery: You just posted a fiddle demonstrating that it works (at least in FF4).

Comment: @nokul: You did not set its `visibility` to `none`. You set its `display` CSS style to `none`. Difference!

Comment: If you are looking a cross browser solution, there is no way to do this. Just testing in FF or Chrome or IE is not going to help you.

Comment: @anothershrubery: Then let's get an answer that actually talks about what browsers this works on.

Comment: My answer addressed the cross browser issue.

Comment: @anothershrubery: Your answer didn't even mention it.

Comment: Didn't think it would have to. Seeing as you want a website to work cross browser I would only want answers that work cross browser.

Comment: Doesn't matter, I'm just in one of those moods today.

Comment: @Tomalak: you're right about the attribute, edited. And I admit I didn't actually test it in IE because I use this a lot and it works in FF and IE. I just didn't use it on <option> tags so far. Strange that _this_ doesn't work. Maybe @user311130 should accept Tomalak's answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the

```
    <span style="display:none">
```

option. You can toggle this style using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox, you can use the `display` style:

```
<select id="s" name="ddl" size="1">
    <option id="a1">Option 1</option>
    <option id="a2">Option 2</option>
    <option id="a3">Option 3</option>
    <option id="a4">Option 4</option>
    <option id="a5">Option 5</option>
</select>
```

and:

```
document.getElementById("a3").style.display = "none";
```

However, this *will not work* on Internet Explorer. For IE, you can only [remove the element entirely](http://jsfiddle.net/jz69X/) (possibly re-adding it later):

```
document.getElementById("s").options[2] = null;
```

You could *move* the element to a separate, hidden `<select />` if you want to store it somewhere for adding back later.

Answer (score -1):

The only thing you can do is removing the option.

You can do this simply in jQuery by:

```
$('#yourOptionId').remove();
```

Or you can disable the option by:

```
$('#yourOptionId').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

And enable by:

```
$('#yourOptionId').removeAttr("disabled");
```

But no there is no way to simply hide an option.

By "ddl control" I'm assuming the structure will be like:

```
<select id="selectId">
    <option id="optionId"></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Explain then, rather than just negging and leaving a useless comment.